# NGINX how to process specific url match as html not php

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I got static pages with filenames like : atatat.php?article=3

i need to process them as html. All with "atatat.php" matching in filename.

And other pages, regular *.php without "atatat.php" matching in url process as usuall php, is that possible with nginx config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nginx regular expression matching:

```
location ~* atatat.php {
  // this will match any url that contains `atatat.php`
  // do whatever you want with them here
}

location ~* [^(atatat)].php {
  // this will match any url that **doesn't** contain `atatat.php`
  // do whatever you want with them here
}
```

The `~*` tells nginx to treat the next part as a case-insensitive regular expression. If you need it to be case-sensitive, just use `~` (remove asterisk).